# How to set Image to text background with parallax effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to achieve the effect for text background as image. Image should be with parallax effect.

I tried below code but not able to work like how I want. Please suggest the best solution with **CSS / JS** whichever is better for this case.

Is there any alternatives avail to do this or any tricks I even tried masking, but not achieved goal.

#### Code Below

```js
let mouseX, mouseY, trackX, trackY;

document.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
    trackX = (4 * mouseX / 170) + 40;
    trackY = (4 * mouseY / 170) + 50;
    document.querySelector(".title").style.backgroundPosition = `${trackX}% ${trackY}%`
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200vmin;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background: #1e5abc;
}

.hero {
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(235, 236, 231), rgb(255, 255, 255));
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 85%, 50% 100%, 0% 85%, 0% 0%);

}

.container {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.right-side-container {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
    clip-path: url(#clipPath);
}

.title {
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470813740244-df37b8c1edcb?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=2b76b1e6da83c1a0f59eebaa481e12aa&auto=format&fit=crop&w=751&q=80") center no-repeat;
    background-position: 40% 50%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    text-anchor: middle;
    alignment-baseline: hanging;
    font-size: calc(12px + 6.2vw);
    text-align: center;
}

.subtitle {
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.35em;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    color: #2b2b2b;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="header-container">
            <br><br><br>
            <br><br><br>
            <div class="title">
                I'm Travis.<br>
                Developer.
            </div>
            <div class="subtitle">
                <p>Frontend - backend - everything</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side-container">
   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying the Parallax image on as Text Color BG not full parallax section image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let mouseX, mouseY, trackX, trackY;

document.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
    trackX = (4 * mouseX / 170) + 40;
    trackY = (4 * mouseY / 170) + 50;
    document.querySelector(".title").style.backgroundPosition = `${trackX}% ${trackY}%`
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200vmin;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background: #1e5abc;
}

.hero {
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(235, 236, 231), rgb(255, 255, 255));
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 85%, 50% 100%, 0% 85%, 0% 0%);

}

.container {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.right-side-container {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
    clip-path: url(#clipPath);
}

.title {
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470813740244-df37b8c1edcb?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=2b76b1e6da83c1a0f59eebaa481e12aa&auto=format&fit=crop&w=751&q=80") center no-repeat;
    background-position: 40% 50%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    text-anchor: middle;
    alignment-baseline: hanging;
    font-size: calc(12px + 6.2vw);
    text-align: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.subtitle {
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.35em;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    color: #2b2b2b;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="header-container">
            <br><br><br>
            <br><br><br>
            <div class="title">
                I'm Travis.<br>
                Developer.
            </div>
            <div class="subtitle">
                <p>Frontend - backend - everything</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side-container">
   
    </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know this is what you are looking for

Comment: Right `background-attachment: fixed;` after adding this it's worked perfectly. Appreciate your work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let offset = window.pageYOffset;
  document.querySelector('.title').style.backgroundPositionY = offset * 0.7 + 'px';
});
```

```css
.title {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.firstcry.com/education/2022/04/25155522/1378635314.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.title-text {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <div class="title-text">
    <h1>I'm Travis</h1>
    <h2>
    The developer
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

put this line in css

```
.title{
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Nizal actually my demo is not perfect when I make that works with multiple iterations.
And just changing `css` will not work here. I am looking for better alternative for it or fix for issue.

Comment: I am trying to add text color as background image and it will parallax when page scrolled. Did you get my point if not please let me know. Thanks for involving to find some new thing.